# How to create focusable horizontal field manager in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I need focusable horizontal field manager,for this i found some code in forums.

```
        hfm[i]=new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FOCUSABLE)
        {
            protected void onFocus(int direction)
            {
                Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createLinearGradientBackground(0x00E2E2E2,0x00E2E2E2,0x00E2E2E2,0x00E2E2E2);
                setBackground(bg);
            }

            protected void onUnfocus()
            {
                Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createLinearGradientBackground(0x00FFFFFF,0x00FFFFFF,0x00FFFFFF,0x00FFFFFF);
                setBackground(bg);
            }
        };
rtf[i]=new ExtendedLabel(list[i]);
hfm[i].add(rtf[i]);
add(hfm[i]);
```

But the it is not focusable,if it

Comment: check out ListStyleButtonField in case this is what you are trying to re-create: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276

Comment: thank for your support this is link is very helpful for learning other concepts also

Answer (score 3):

You should also add this method to your new HorizontalFieldManager

```
public boolean isFocusable(){
    return true;
}
```

Remember though when you set a manager to be focusable in this way it must have a field within it that is focusable or else you will get a null exception when the screen tries to give your managae focus.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem that happens to everyone at least one time. 
I started a topic in BB support forum:
[Scroll happening but Vertical Field Manager Not Moving](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Scroll-happening-but-Vertical-Field-Manager-Not-Moving/m-p/1214481)

And the answer given was the blackberry support forum article:
[My scrollable manager is not scrolling](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/My-scrollable-manager-is-not-scrolling/ta-p/445247)

That is not a real answer but is the only workaround that's available for the moment

Another posible solution to this is:

> A friend gave me the solution... you can put your manager into an
>   horizontal manager and then you can just add an nullfield with a
>   focusable behaviour, This will do the trick

You can try that.

Comment: by using above links label field with different heights are focusable.But i need horizontal field manager to get focus

Comment: did you try to add the nullfield?
to Where is hfm added to?

Answer (score 0):

You give focus to this.

```
rtf[i]=new ExtendedLabel(list[i]);
```

as....

```
rtf[i]=new ExtendedLabel(list[i],Field.Focusable);
```